# Error: The JMS Connection has failed: java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

```
org.apache.activemq.ConnectionFailedException: The JMS connection has failed: java.io.EOFException
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.checkClosedOrFailed(ActiveMQConnection.java:1480)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:324)
```

Any solution for this appreciated?

Answer (score 4):

The underlying exception reported by the ActiveMQ JMS client implementation is a `java.io.EOFException`. [The documentation for this exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html) states:

> Signals that an end of file or end of stream has been reached unexpectedly during input.
>
> This exception is mainly used by data input streams to signal end of stream. Note that many other input operations return a special value on end of stream rather than throwing an exception.

Therefore it appears that the network connection between the client and server failed. The specific root cause for the failure cannot be determined by the information you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

We have faced the same issue. Reason which we have found is that we were starting the **Publisher/Producer** before starting the **JMS Broker** . As we know after starting **JMS Broker** only **Publisher/Producer** is established the connection with **JSM Broker** .

We have take the following approach and problem is solved.

Solution: Please first start **JMS Broker** then **Publisher/Producer** and then **Consumer**.

[image]

Comment: No, you dont need a JMS Broker if you only consume from another broker.